# How to pick the right template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2015

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio, and most of the time when I start a new project, I just follow what template the person in the tutorial pick.

Now that I actually looked at it, I realize there are quite a few variation of templates to choose from when starting a new project!

Examples for Visual C# like:
Windows Forms Application,
WPF Application,
Console application,
ASP.NET Web Application,
Shared Project,
and Class Library.

[image]

So, my question is how do I pick the right template for the right project? Like for now I'm planning to play around with some console application, and if it works I would love to move them to mobile apps. Is that possible? Whatever I've made, are they transferable?

Right now it feels like I have to pick the perfect template right off the bat so that I don't one day have to start all over again!

Comment: You can always create an empty solution and add the projects to it that you see fit.